# OpenBMC as layer in another Yocto project

Tags: openbmc

I am trying to include OpenBMC as a part of another Yocto-based build.  For many reasons, not the least of which this is a Xilinx SoC image built with Petalinux, I need the OpenBMC components in a standard meta layer that can be included, just like with a browser, etc.  Everything I have found with OpenBMC seems to believe that OpenBMC is the center of the universe and I have to shoehorn the board into their build.

Has anyone used OpenBMC as a proper meta layer as opposed to the overall build?
I prefer to not hand-modify the components to work as that would break being able to pull updates easily.